# How to use index and match concept to retrieve values from 2nd row and 3rd column or 1st row and 4th column and so on

Tags: excel

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May
1   10  110 101 11  90
2   20  111 102 12  91
3   30  112 103 13  92
4   40  113 104 14  93
5   50  114 105 15  94
```

How to use index and match concept to retrieve values from 2nd row and 3rd column  or 1st row and 4th column and so on

Comment: can someone convert my values to table .

Comment: can someone convert my values to table. im not sure how to do it. 1 ,2,3,4,5 are column headers and han,feb,march,apr, may are row headers

Comment: "And so on" is unclear to me. What's the pattern in (2,3), (1,4),...?

Comment: the pattern can be anything - like retrieve the field value for 1st colum , 3rd row or 5th colums ,2nd row. I need to have generic formula using index and match to achieve it. Thanks

Comment: That's not a pattern. Just write `retrieve values`, the random cell numbers you wrote might suggest that you want more than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to match cell $B$2 (Row 2, Column "February") you could use the following formula:

```
INDEX(B1:B5, MATCH(91, E1:E5, 0))
```

This would give the value 111, which is the value of $B$2

The `INDEX` function in Excel takes a range (B1:B5) and an index into that range, and returns the value.  In an `INDEX MATCH`, the index used is actually a call to the `MATCH` function.  Here, I obtained an index of 2 when MATCHing the value 91 in the range E1:E5.

In English you might read this call as saying "Find the value in the range B1 to B5 whose index is the same as the value 91 in the range E1 to E5."

Comment: ok will the same formula work if I ask to retrieve 3rd column - mar and 5th row - 5 and answer should be 105

Comment: Try using `INDEX(C1:C5, MATCH(94, E1:E5, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

If the months are in `B1:F1`, row labels in `A2:A6` and main body of the table in `B2:F6` then you can get the value at the intersection of the `nth` row and `kth` column of `B2:F6` using this formula

`=INDEX(B2:F6,n,k)`

As per Tim's answer you can derive the n and k values using `MATCH` functions based on the values in the column headers and row labels, e.g. matching `"Apr"` and `4` will give you the value at the intersection, i.e. `14`

and the formula would look like this

`=INDEX(B2:F6,MATCH(4,A2:A6,0),MATCH("feb",B1:F1,0))`

see [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html#IndexMatch3) for more